# Convert Exponential value to Decimal

Tags: vbscript, qtp

Any idea how to convert exponential value into decimal value. I have below code which returns as 1.00000000000051E-02 but I would like to display as 0.01 (100-99.99)

```
Dim total
Dim pct

total = 99.99

pct=(100-total)

msgbox pct
```

Comment: Post your trying clearly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`Round`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/se6f2zfx%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) function:

```
Dim total
Dim pct

total = 99.99
pct = Round(100-total, 2)

MsgBox pct
```